# How to fade-in a render layer in compositor

Tags: animation, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am trying to fade-in four render layers and not having much success. I have looked at this solution
[Fade a render layer to transparent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27319/fade-a-render-layer-to-transparent)
but it does not seem to work for me, probably due to my set up. When I attempt this solution I do not get the desired fade-in results. Here's my compositor set up. [image: The compositor set up.]

I am trying to fade-in the iMac and iPhone layers (4 layers in total). Here's a close up of the two iPhone layers.
[image: close up of the iPhone layers]

Can anyone suggest a way to get the iMac and iPhone layers to fade in over time? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't just keyframing the mix factor do what you want?

Comment: Regus - thanks for taking the time to make a suggestion. I don't have a Mix node anywhere.  I tried adding a mix node in here and there, but that wasn't working. BUT - your suggestion gave me the idea that maybe I don't have to add anything. And what do you know!!! Adjusting the factor setting on the last Alpha Over node (right most Alpha Over node) in a layer gives me the transparency I can animate. So thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I meant the Alpha Over mix factor. :P Glad that worked for you!